# How to sort the inner array of a multidimensional array based on the input string value in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a search feature using PHP. When we give an input string, it should sort the result array values based on the input given. The array with most matching result should get listed first.
When I tried sorting, the result got arranged based on their alphabetic order. It would be nice if somebody could help me.
Here's my array,

```
$sourceArray = array( Array
    (
        'name' => 'MODERN FAMILY SPINOFF AKA CORRIGAN, PAUL & BRAD WALSH PROJECT',
         'status' => 'D',
        'season' => '2014-2015',
     ),
Array
    (
        'name' => 'E! ENTERTAINMENT SPECIAL: MODERN FAMILY',
        'status' => 'D',
        'season' => '2014-2015',
    ),
Array
    (
        'name' => 'MODERN FAMILY AKA MY AMERICAN FAMILY AKA LEVITAN, STEVEN & LLOYD, CHRIS PROJECT',
        'status' => 'D',
        'season' => '2009-2010'
    ),
Array
    (
        'name' => 'MODERN FAMILY',
        'status' => 'P',
        'season' => '2015-2016',
    ),
Array
    (
        'name' => 'E! ENTERTAINMENT SPECIAL: MODERN FAMILY',
        'status' => 'P',
        'season' => '2013-2014',
    ),    Array
    (
        'name' => 'E! ENTERTAINMENT SPECIAL: MODERN FAMILY',
        'status' => 'D',
        'season' => '2014-2015',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you in sorting multidimensional array based on the input string value. Also it allows to match exact string and also sub string. Mention the second portion of the string in the **Break point**

```
usort($sourceArray, 'name_sort');


print_r($sourceArray);



function name_sort($a, $b) {
global $incVal;
$incVal++;

$sampleText =  "Your Text Input";

if(strcmp($a['name'],$sampleText)==0 && strcmp($b['name'],$sampleText)==0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    if(strcmp($a['name'],$sampleText)==0)
    {

        return -1;
    }
}

if(strpos($a['name'],$sampleText)=== false)
{
     if(strpos($b['name'],$sampleText)=== false)
    {
         return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        $b = explode($sampleText,$b['name']);// $b['name'];
        if(strpos($b[1],'Break Point')== 1)
              {

                  return 1;
              }
              elseif(strpos($a[1],'Break Point')== 1)
              {

                  return -1;
              }
              else 
                {

                  return 0;

                }

    }
}
else
{
    if(strpos($b['name'],$sampleText)=== false)
    {
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {
         $a = explode($sampleText,$a['name']);//$a['name'];
         $b = explode($sampleText,$b['name']);// $b['name'];


              if(strpos($b[1],'Break Point')== 1)
              {

                  return 1;
              }
              elseif(strpos($a[1],'Break Point')== 1)
              {

                  return -1;
              }
              elseif(strpos($b[1],'Break Point')> 1)
              {

                  return 1;
              }
              else {

                  return 0;

                  }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to return array keys that match your search criteria:

```
$results = array_keys(array_column($sourceArray, 'name'), 'Family');
```